# Where can I ask about the Tile Bluetooth tracker?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a site where I can ask questions about the [Tile](https://www.thetileapp.com/)? It is a Bluetooth tracking device which can be configured using a smartphone app.

Example question: I recently purchased a new Tile. I want to ask whether it is possible transfer my old name, photo, and ringtone over to the new device.

I could imagine it possibly being on-topic for Super User, Internet of Things, or Ask Different.

Comment: Not really on topic on SU. maybe IOT? It is a IOT device, but you'd need to check there.